# Populating Table Layout android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

can someone please help me.... I am trying to populate a table with some values from a database that updates everytime a score is recieved... For some reason my tables are not being updated with the new score.

This is my code: (Thanks in advance)

```
**/**
 * 
 */
package group6.scoresheet;

import group6.scoresheet.model.DataStore;
import group6.scoresheet.model.Game;
import group6.scoresheet.model.GamePlayer;
import group6.scoresheet.model.GameTeam;
import group6.scoresheet.model.Player;
import group6.scoresheet.model.Team;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This displays the Team's scores.
 * Called when the user clicks the Team stats tab
 * @author NiraliPatel
 *
 */
public class TeamStatistics extends Activity {

    private Team team1 = null;
    private Team team2 = null;
    private int teamOne = 0;
    private int teamTwo = 1;
    private DataStore dataStore = null;
    Game game;
    Player player;
    Team team;
    TableLayout t1;
    TableLayout t2;

    /** Called when the activity is created */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.team_stats);
        this.dataStore = (DataStore)getApplicationContext();
        game = dataStore.getCurrentGame();
        // Get the two teams that are playing
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        {
            this.teamOne = extras.getInt("teamOne");
            this.teamTwo = extras.getInt("teamTwo");
        }

        this.team1 = this.dataStore.getTeams().get(this.teamOne);
        this.team2 = this.dataStore.getTeams().get(this.teamTwo);

        populate();

    }
    /**
     * Populates the lists with the Teams scores
     */
    public void populate()
    {

        Team team1 = getTeam(1);
        Team team2 = getTeam(2);

        TextView team1Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Team1);
        team1Name.setText(team1.getName());

        TextView team2Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Team2);
        team2Name.setText(team2.getName());

        Map<Team, Integer> score_1 = this.game.getScore();

        String[] scoreType = {"Total Score:", "Home Runs:", "Total Balls:", "Total Outs:"};
        String[] t1Scores = {Integer.toString(score_1.get(this.team1)), "0", "0", "0"};
        String[] t2Scores = {Integer.toString(score_1.get(this.team2)), "0", "0", "0"};

        t1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableTeamDataT1);
        for(int i = 0; i < scoreType.length; i++){
            teamRow(t1, scoreType[i] , t1Scores[i]);
        }
        t2 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableTeamDataT2);
        for(int i = 0; i < scoreType.length; i++){
            teamRow(t2, scoreType[i] , t2Scores[i]);
        }

    }
    public void teamRow(TableLayout table, String col1, String col2){
                TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
                //Create text views to be added to the row.
                TextView tvScore = new TextView(this);
                TextView tvScoreValue = new TextView(this);

                //Put the data into the text view by passing it to a user defined function createView()
                createView(tr1, tvScore, col1);
                createView(tr1, tvScoreValue, col2);
                /**if(heading){
                    tr1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    //tr1.setGravity(5);
                    tvName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tvRbi.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tvHomeRuns.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }*/
                //Add the new row to our tableLayout tl
                table.addView(tr1);
    }

            public void createView(TableRow tr1, TextView t, String viewdata) {
                t.setText(viewdata);
                tr1.addView(t); // add TextView to row.
                }





    /**
     * Gets a team given the team number
     * @param   teamNumber  The number of the team to be selected (1 for team 1, 2 for team 2)
     * @return              The team
     */
    private Team getTeam(int teamNumber)
    {
        Team team = null;

        switch(teamNumber)
        {
        case 1:
            team = this.team1;
            break;
        case 2:
            team = this.team2;
            break;
        }

        return team;
    }   

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //populate();
    }
}



**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF004000"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TeamStatsHeader" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableTeamDataT1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Team2"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableTeamRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Team1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/Teams"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableTeamDataT2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/Team2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tableTeamDataT1"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableTeamRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Team2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="102dp"
                android:text="@string/Teams"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TeamStatsHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/TeamStats"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40dp" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/finish_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TeamStatsHeader"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:text="@string/Continue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to write `invalidate()`;

```
linearMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearmainLayout);

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    linearMain.removeAllViews();
    linearMain.invalidate();

    AddLayout();
}
```

See I add table layout like this. I am dynamically creating `TableLayout` and adding that in a `LinearLayout` that I declared in XML layout file

```
    TableLayout tableContainer = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    TableLayout.LayoutParams tab_lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    tableContainer.setLayoutParams(tab_lp);

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

    final TextView tvProduct = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_l3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvProduct.setLayoutParams(lp_l3);
    tvProduct.setText(product);

    row.addView(tvProduct,  new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));
    tableContainer.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams()); 

    linearMain.addView(tableContainer);
```

Comment: It is layout in which I add views

Comment: Im sorry but im confused about how i use/declare it... is it the layout in the xml file i used to put the tables in... (btw we have the same name :)  )

Comment: Hi. i see how you adding the table layouts as you go... But i have already added table layouts to my xml file... i have added my xml code above... is there any other way of updating the values in the table without duplication..? Thankyou